# How to connect android application to postgresql

Tags: android, postgresql

I am new to postgresql. I need to connect to a database on my computer. I've tried changing url but with no success. Every time the application crashes. Perhaps my server is not configured properly. But I don't understand anything about this.

It's code of my activity

```
package com.example.conference.activity

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast

import com.example.conference.R
import com.example.conference.adapter.ViewPagerAdapter

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.sql.DriverManager

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mainVP.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        mainVP.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        mainTL.setupWithViewPager(mainVP)

        val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"

        val con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "elzahaggard13")
        val statement = con.createStatement()
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, id, email, surname) VALUES (alex, 2901, strontium2001@mail.ru, smit)")

        statement.close()
        con.close()
    }
}
```